# how to send some data eg strings to a local web server with iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i want to send a file from my iphone which have some strings to a local web server with iphone sdk?how can i do it ?is there any sample code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is a common way of doing it, but you could also use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). An example on using NSURLConnection to post data can easily be found. [Conceited Code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376821/conceited-code) has a couple of tutorials showing both [general use](http://www.conceitedcode.com/2010/06/using-nsurlconnection/) of NSURLConnection and [posting data](http://www.conceitedcode.com/2010/06/sending-post-data-using-nsurlconnection/) with it.

ASIHttpRequest also has some [simple examples](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest) that should get you going.